# Какая разница между $array['var'] или $array->var в PHP?

Tags: php

Часто вижу что в исходниках открытых проектов встречается второй вариант. Есть ли различие между ними? Если нет, использование того или иного варианта вопрос вкуса?

Comment: в варианте ` $array->var` наверное беред массивом тоже есть стрелка от чего-то еще, типа такого `$News->$array->var` и тогда это вопрос к ООП.... просто `$array['var']` - массив не относящийся к классу....... без класса написать `$array->var` нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array['var']` - обращение к элементу var массива $array

`$array->var` - обращение к свойству var объекта $array

В PHP - объекты и массивы имеют разницу. В JS например не имеют - там сойдут любые операторы.